# Add Facebook SDK iOS Sticker Pack

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-sdk-4.0, imessage-extension

I have followed the instructions on Facebook about adding the SDK framework to an existing iOS project, but creating an iOS sticker pack is slightly different as it doesn't have an AppDelegate. Has anyone successfully been able to add this SDK to an iMessage sticker pack, and if so what steps am I missing
Thanks